# online radio streaming not working in android with mediaplayer.setDataSource method

Tags: android

Online radio streaming in android not working with `mediaplayer.setDataSource` method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final static String RADIO_STATION_URL = "http://tunein.com/radio/Hindi-Desi-Bollywood-Evergreen-Hits-s129208/";

    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

    private Button buttonPlay;

    private Button buttonStopPlay;

    private Button buttonRecord;

    private Button buttonStopRecord;

    private MediaPlayer player;

    private InputStream recordingStream;

    private RecorderThread recorderThread;

    private boolean isRecording = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeUIElements();

        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }
    private void initializeUIElements() {

        playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        playSeekBar.setMax(100);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
        buttonRecord.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonStopRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopRecord);
        buttonStopRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
            stopPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonRecord) {
            recorderThread = new RecorderThread();
            recorderThread.start();

            buttonRecord.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStopRecord.setEnabled(true);
        } else if (v == buttonStopRecord) {
            stopRecording();
        }

    }


    private void startPlaying() {
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
                buttonRecord.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            initializeMediaPlayer();
        }

        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buttonRecord.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
        stopRecording();
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {

        BufferedOutputStream writer = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(RADIO_STATION_URL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            final String FOLDER_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + "Songs";

            File folder = new File(FOLDER_PATH);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(FOLDER_PATH
                    + File.separator + "sample.mp3")));
            recordingStream = connection.getInputStream();

            final int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            while (recordingStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) != -1 && isRecording) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                writer.flush();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                recordingStream.close();
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        buttonStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
        buttonRecord.setEnabled(true);
        try {
            isRecording = false;
            if (recordingStream != null) {
                recordingStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class RecorderThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isRecording = true;
            startRecording();
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. And your exact question is? What does "not work" mean. Giving errors? Which kind of?

Comment: in above code the method streams the mp3 media file but it shows continuous buffering when the url of online radio station passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code and immediately noticed something, the link you used isn't a direct link to the audio file you want to stream, it should look more like http://192.240.102.133:11454/stream which is the correct url instead of http://tunein.com/radio/Hindi-Desi-Bollywood-Evergreen-Hits-s129208 you could learn how to get the direct url's from tunein here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-a-streaming-URL-for-Tunein